# detailed meaning of ?- X is X+1

Tags: prolog

While studying the language Prolog I found the following true or false question:

> In Prolog `?- X is X+1` results in the increment of the variable `X` by one.

A teacher said it's false, however I don't understand why. Won't `X` be `X+1` from now on? Why is it false?

Comment: In Prolog `X is X + 1` is saying that `X` has the same value as `X+1` which obviously is false. It's not a new assignment of `X` as in other languages. Once the value of `X` has been established, it cannot be changed except through backtracking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prolog does not work with *variables* like elements that can change value. A variable is an element that currently has no value, once it has a value, it cannot change that value (except for backtracking in which the unification is undone).

In case `X` already has a value, `X+1` will be calculated, but you cannot *unify* `3` with `4`:

```
?- X=3, X is X+1.
false.
```

In case `X` is ungrounded at that moment, the `is` predicate will fail:

```
?- X is X+1.
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

The question probably wants to demonstrate one of the fundamental differences between imperative programming and logic programming: in imperative programming a variable can be *assigned* a (new) value, in logic programming a variable can only *grounded* once (except for backtracking). Once fully grounded, you cannot *ground* it a different way.